# Nginx/Passenger/Ruby error: Cannot execute ruby. Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

After upgrading Passenger to 1.5.10 on Ubuntu, my rails app won't run. Passenger gives me an error:

`Cannot execute /root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/wrappers/ruby: Permission denied (13)`

The ruby executable path is valid, and I can run it from the command line. The file is owned by root:rvm, and nginx is running as www-data:www-data, so I figured that mismatch was the problem, but even when I change the ruby owner to www-data, I still have the same issue.

As far as I can tell from the Passenger tutorial, everything is set up correctly. From my nginx.conf:

```
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/wrappers/ruby;
passenger_user www-data;
passenger_group www-data;
```

And in the site configuration, I set `passenger_enabled on`.

So now I'm stumped and would be grateful for assistance.

Comment: 99% chance that this is SELinux related. Have you tried disabling it as a test? `sudo setenforce 0`

Comment: Just tried it. Didn't help.

Comment: There is a near-zero chance that `www-data` can read `/root/`. So it can't execute anything under that path.

Comment: Thank you, Camden, but surely I don't have to run nginx as root for passenger to work. Also, this was working fine as www-data before I upgraded nginx and passenger.

Comment: Sorry, Camden. I see your point now. But why would passenger try to execute /root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/wrappers/ruby when I set passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/wrappers/ruby?

Comment: Got it! I did have `passenger_ruby /root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/wrappers/ruby` incorrectly set in an old version of the site-enabled server block, which was overriding nginx.conf. Uff, the problem was right before my eyes the whole time. Thanks for the tip, Camden.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Cameron's comment ^, I discovered that I had set passenger_ruby to the wrong path in my nginx server block. The ruby executable specified there was under /root and therefore inaccessible to www-data.